Integral of $e^{-x^2}$
As we all know that integral of the function $e^{-x^2}$ is a non elementary function in the form of an error function.
But can we calculate it's values at particular points for example the integral from $-1$ to $1$ in a numerical value.
Also say if we can not then van we construct an elementary function using the difference between $2$ values equal to the area under the the curve and finding the area manually?

Generally, we can't calculate its values; we can only approximate them.

FYI, there are points for which the value will be nice. For example, there exist values for $a$ and $b$ (in fact, infinitely many, even uncountably many) such that the integral from $a$ to $b$ is exactly $\frac{1}{2}.$ However, those values for $a$ and $b$ will likely not be expressible in any nice closed form manner. (I don't know if it's known that no such values for $a$ and $b$ exist, as this is different from the indefinite integral having no closed form, but it's almost certainly the case that no such values for $a$ and $b$ are known, otherwise such values would probably be widely known.)
